# Conditional comments not functioning

Tags: html, css, conditional-statements

I'm building a website which needs to use a custom font through @font-face. IE only displays if I use an .eot extension; other browsers only if I use a .ttf extension.

I can't work out though how to use conditional comments to use both - even though I've tried loads of suggestions on the web... Nothing's working for me.

Essentially, I have:

```
<style>
@font-face{
font-family: Square;
src: url(/wpadmin/fonts/Square.ttf);
}

@font-face{
font-family: Square_IE;
src: url(/wpadmin/fonts/Square.eot);
}

</style>

<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<style>
#Title{
font-family:Square;
}
</style>
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]><!-->
<style>
#Title{
font-family:Square_IE;
}
</style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The font only displays correctly in IE here - not in other browsers. If I remove the [if IE] statement, it then displays correctly in other browsers.

I've tried lots of variations, including conditional statements within the html body.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but I think the [if IE] part should be inside the comments, so that other browsers ignore it

Comment: You haven't said what version of IE, but conditional comments don't work from version 11

Comment: You have to use `-ms-` as a prefix for IE specific css.

Comment: It is IE11 - I had heard that newer versions of IE don't support the comments... That's why I put !IE first, in the hope that other browsers would pick that up, but that IE would just be over-ridden by the second comment. But what's the solution then - can I not do conditional CSS at all with IE now?

Comment: Thanks Rajeshwar - but where? I tried -ms-font-family: within the #Title css, but it doesn't work... Can anyone point me to an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional comments don't work from IE 11, but also this isn't the standard approach. You don't need different font names, you can just do this for a cross-browser list of font files all referencing one name.

```
/* declare all the files - browser will use the best it understands */

@font-face {
   font-family: 'Square';
   src:url('Square.eot');
   src:url('Square.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('Square.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('Square.woff') format('woff'),
       url('Square.svg#Square') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


/* now just reference the one name */

#Title {
  font-family:Square;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim - it's not working either tho - with this it's displaying properly in IE but not in other browsers...

Comment: Ah - works now - I tweaked a bit - thank you. It seems to like only one src: line, rather than two.

Comment: I would expect IE11 to be using the TTF font anyway. http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf